# Rim suspension?

Tags: suspension, rim-tape, nipples

Is there any professional suspension system applicable between rim and nipples ?

Did some tests on road bike with narrowest tyres long time ago with positive results. Wondering if there exist anything similar ready made now ?

Do not respond no, do not know, impossible and similar spam. Thank you.

---

Edit 3

Tested gum also under dropouts / over Through Axles, is there any possibility pipe can move a bit in dropouts then or is it fixed hard ? Not sure how to check if it has any measurable effect.

---

Edit

Not asking moderators, etc. 1st unasked answer is off-topic - nipple, gum(?) layer, rim does not sound like outer end of spoke ??

---

Edit 2

If someone prefer pictures. Base taken from [RIMs](https://dspace.vsb.cz/bitstream/handle/10084/117365/SNE0024_FS_B2341_2302R010_40_2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), [Asphalts](https://www.vutbr.cz/www_base/zav_prace_soubor_verejne.php?file_id=78057).
Mind common narrow rires with recommended pressure around 8bars.
[image: Idea compilation]

---

[image: Image from https://bikebooboos.com/repairs/wheeltruing/ but relabelled by Criggie]

Here are the English names for the parts of a wheel, for consistency.

Comment: "Do not respond no, do not know, impossible and similar spam." - However, what if the answer is actually no?

Comment: So, is the actual question about breaking spokes?

Comment: Btw, in a way the spoke suspension exists. Thinner spokes are more flexible and do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm guessing that English is not Tom's native language - that's okay, just work with us all on the wording so it is accurate.

Comment: Tom, the post could be improved by removing the comments about idiots and spam. People downvoting and commenting are not spammers. The comments point out genuine issues with your questions.

Comment: "Not asking moderators, downvoters, etc." Ohhhh, I get it. You can post anything you want if you just ask the moderators to stay away. In real life, you don't get to come into a community and impose your own standards on it.

Comment: "Also spices do not need to get all kicks from tyres or tensions from rim."... please get someone to translate.

Comment: You keep using the word spam, but it seems you do not know what it means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98172/discussion-between-ojs-and-tom).

Comment: @Tom I don't know why you post here. Every time you post, you complain about the way we treat you. Let me be blunt: it's because every time you come here, you act like a jerk. Please just go away.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you meant something in the rim's spoke holes - the initial description was unclear. The problem is that what you describe can't be a suspension system in the way that most cyclists understand it. Suspension systems  damp vertical, i.e. up-down shocks. There has to be some vertical travel. What you describe could damp things horizontally from the perspective of a spoke. I have no idea what purpose that would serve. Please also clarify what you mean by "It was proven by me" - did you actually made something like this? Why? If you did, why can't you describe it better?

Comment: In short looking for a way to overcome for example poor asphalt quality keeping high tyre pressure, but using additional pad to reduce small vibrations. Already used that, but looking for a ready made "plug and play" solution. Do not want to play with material width, elasticity, possible spoke length extension, acceptable load, etc.

Comment: Tom, I don't think the system you describe will do anything to improve comfort. As I said, I don't think it will create any vertical suspension at all. If it does, it will offer less vertical travel than the air in your tires does. As Criggie already said, wider tires and lower pressure. It's a widely used system. People are starting to realize that this setup often has lower rolling resistance than narrow tires also. Basically, the answer to your original question is no.

Comment: The main problem with the idea is that while it doesn't add much vertical compliance, it will make the wheel laterally wobbly because the rubber pieces for one side can be compressed while other side extends.

Comment: And please, "narrow beat fat" or "best fat" do not make any sense and "rought" is not even English.

Comment: It also depends - there is at least say 5mm empty space in common rim and also some stress in spokes, so not 1:1 on spokes move up/down.

Comment: Ok, possible @ some occasions - resistance is driven by tyre mass deformed and pressure, but wider must have lower maximal pressure (both rim mechanical endurance and tyre construction) so even having similar mass possibly deformed, narrow wins over fat by higher pressure option / smaller contact area (pressure = force/area). So you cannot pump best fat to same pressure and then cannot wins in resistance comparision of best narrow. And when train wheels use similar gum layer to decrease noice, it must suspend small bumps. Asphalt rough difference is tiny, so there is space for that too.

Comment: If native have problems understanding their language https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatbike a bit extreme, but fat bike and tyres are common terms.

Comment: Tom, your last 3 comments are hard to understand. Unfortunately, almost all the questions you ask or comments you make are unclear! The last diagram you drew seems to add some sort of material around the spoke nipple, inside the rim. The damping material is between the spoke and the rim bed. However, the links you provided don't contain the picture you drew, and they're in what I assume is Czech. You will need to have them translated if you expect us to treat them seriously. And you'll need to show where the concept you're trying to convey is discussed in each paper.

Comment: Diagram is a mixture of pictures in mentioned links - that is all - I am not author of them. Concept is as I can tell not discussed anywhere (that is why I am asking). It was only tested by me on my old road bike long time ago - also mentioned in original question. Goal was move suspension out of tyres (causing higher resistance), but not too far - to protect rest of bike (or most of mass/weight + rider) from vibrations, bumps, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better to change rim or tyre size to get lower rolling resistance on trekking tyre?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/63479/better-to-change-rim-or-tyre-size-to-get-lower-rolling-resistance-on-trekking-ty)

Answer (score 8):

I have never heard of anything like this, and here are my thoughts on why this concept has not been made:

My guess is that suspension at the rim and outer end of the spoke will effectively re-tension the spoke every time the rim rotates.  Suspension only works when it has room to move in both directions, and also has a damper to resist oscillation.

We know that one of the chief causes of broken spokes at the J-bend is when the spoke is too loose.  A suspension unit on the spoke would have to flex to do any absorption of vibration, which would effectively tighten and loosen the spoke continuously.  This will lead to metal fatigue and to broken spokes.

---

**Braking/cornering feedback loop**

A wheel is a three dimensional system - there are side forces from pedalling, from the ridden-surface, and from braking.  Any and all of those could set up a feedback oscillation that would have unpredictable effects on riding.  You do not want play in any part of your wheel.

---

**Concept wheels**

Some wheels do exist that replace spokes or tyres with other systems. but for various reasons they haven't caught on.  Spokes are cheap and well understood.

[image: https://www.wired.com/2013/05/loopwheel/]

> in-wheel suspensions are nearly as old as the bicycle itself, but the designs always failed because they were too heavy or too flimsy.   (from https://www.wired.com/2013/05/loopwheel/ )

Imagine a hard braking effort on that wheel.  It would wind up, storing energy which would push you backward hard when the forward momentum went to zero and the brake was released.

---

On the positive side, there is already a suspension item in that area, being the **air inside your tire/tyre**.  A taller and wider tyre at a  lower pressure will provide more effective suspension than anything in the spokes could do.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.engadget.com/amp/2019/06/04/gm-and-michelin-airless-tires/ even "in tyre" suspension exists yet...

Comment: All suspension systems have some energy loss. Air inside tyres is the least lossy. That thing from Michelin is trying to replicate that and be totally puncture proof at the same time.

Comment: Michelin is replacing the tire to make it air-less, not adding suspension to the rim itself.

Comment: Please don't encourage this guy by answering his questions. He already said he doesn't want to hear from moderators and doesn't want to hear from people who say that the answer is "no".

Comment: I feel differently to David on that, I think that patiently explaining why you don't think this has been done is a great thing to do. The question is such a mess that I can't fathom an answer but you have put forward one which i think is very good (even +6 is probably an above average score for most questions). Everyone entitled to ask a question here is entitled to have it answered after all. So kudos

Comment: @Swifty I dispute that somebody who behaves so consistently obnoxiously is "entitled to ask a question here."

Comment: @DavidRicherby my point was that I feel a moderator (especially) _should_ encourage users to learn how to use the site. If you want to remove the entitlement to ask questions, that is a separate thing. But while questions are accepted from a user, it's fair to do what can be done to answer, and to encourage. I also feel misquoted, I was not making any comment on the OP, I was speaking about "Everyone", a word you have chopped off the quote. Now we are plainly off-topic for the comments, if you want to dispute OPs entitlement, there must be a better place to do that